# Visual Studio Post Build Event - xcopy to different relative directory

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xcopy, post-build-event, post-build

Essentially, what I want to do is use a wildcard for a directory.

The post build event is on a PageComponents project:

```
PageComponents
    WidgetTemplates
        WidgetTemplate1
            Usercontrol1
        WidgetTemplate2
            Usercontrol2
```

And I want to copy all user controls to a Web project, but to a different relative location:

```
Web
    CtrlPresentation
        Usercontrol1
        Usercontrol2
```

I tried to wildcard the WidgetTemplates directory:

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)WidgetTemplates\*\*.ascx" "$(SolutionDir)Client.Web\CtrlPresentation" /y /s`

But this fails all together.  So then I tried the following:

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)WidgetTemplates\*.ascx" "$(SolutionDir)Client.Web\CtrlPresentation" /y /s`

But this copies each individual WidgetTemplate folder over as well.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Jeremy - did you solve this?  I'm trying to solve a very similar problem.

Comment: @itsmatt - No, unfortunately not.  I went with the manual approach of just adding an `xcopy` for each directory I wanted to copy.  I only ended up with about a dozen or so, so it wasn't a huge issue.

Comment: Based on the documentation, it seems like you'd want to omit the `/s`. [link](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true). **/s : Copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty. If you omit /s, xcopy works within a single directory.**. Have you tried running the xcopy command in cmd just to amek sure it's doing what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Task.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MySources Include="$(ProjectDir)WidgetTemplates\**\*.ascx" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyOver">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySources)" DestinationFiles="@(MySources->'$(SolutionDir)Client.Web\CtrlPresentation\%(FileName)%(Extension)')">
</Target>
```

and use this target after your Build

```
<BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    CopyOver
</BuildDependsOn>
```

Comment: If this answered your question, why dont you accept it :)